# Where to find wilderness in Europe?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, hiking

We are crazy and we want an adventure and hiking. We have already visited [NP Sarek](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=cs&sl=cs&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tchorici.cz%2Fakce%2F1-np-sarek-svedsko-2012.html) in northen Sweden and we liked it very much - no men, no bridges, no civilization at all. And now we are looking for another place in Europe untouched by people, where is possible to walk for a week and feel freedom ;)

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I would consider some of the harder to reach parts of Georgia over past Turkey in the Caucasus. Especially up in the mountains.

Comment: This question belongs on, and is answered on, [Outdoors.SE]: [Where in Europe is wilderness meeting the U.S. wilderness definition?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3523/566)

Comment: Sarek National Park is not a proper wilderness.  It is part of the cultural Laponia world heritage, the vegetation is not natural, because the Sami-herder tame reindeer run around.  Naturally occuring animals such as wolves and bears are hunted to extinction due to the competition for reindeer meat.

Comment: I think it belongs on either/both of Travel & Great Outdoors. Take a look at my post on SO.meta about crossover questions like this: **[Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with “crossover questions” between sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989)**

Answer (score 14):

It comes down to the definition you want to adopt but apart from the Northern and Eastern periphery (especially Russia), I think there is no real wilderness in Europe.

You can have some feeling of remoteness in parts of the Alps but the region has been inhabited for centuries and shaped by humans in many subtle ways. You are also never really far from settlements.

I have never been there but I also believe that some parts of the Carpathian mountains could be interesting for you. There are several national parks in different countries (Ukraine, Slovakia, Poland, Romania).

Answer (score 10):

Northern Sweden, yes. But also northern Norway (Svalbard!). Greenland (if that counts as Europe).
There are some old forests that may be of interest as well. Brading on Isle of Wight. Rautas in Kiruna, Sweden. Tyresta National Park quite close to Stockholm, Sweden is quite accessible. Białowieża Forest in Poland... Also in Latvia you can find untouched areas.

Comment: Can you expand on Brading?  Looks like it's [a village in the Isle of Wight](Brading on Isle of Wight), I don't get what that has to do with the question?

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for something untouched by civilization, what about Gorgany in the Ukrainian Carpathian mountains?

Mieczysława Orłowicz wrote in 1919 that this is the unique mountain in Europe, because from its peak you can't see any lights made by humans - no city, no village, no road, only other mountains.

My collegues told me after being there that those words are still current.

Comment: There are many more goodies in Carpathian mountains besides Gorgany. Plenty of streams and waterfalls in the most unexpected places.

Comment: I totally agree. We have visited places around Hoverla.

Answer (score 7):

I'd reccomend northern Scotland and its highlands and islands. [Here's a Guardian travel article on Knoydart and Eigg.](http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2008/aug/10/scotland.walkingholidays) However, it's not truly "untouched", in the sense that it's hard to get more than a few tens of miles away from human habitation, farming or roads. For that you'd have to go into eastern Europe and beyond into central Asia.

Comment: I can recommend either of them, but I would suggest that Fisherfield is even more of a remote wilderness.  Not as pretty as Knoydart, though.

Comment: Scotland (and the rest of Britain) is one of the most severely deforested places on the planet. [Less than 1%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caledonian_Forest) of the original forest is left, and severe overgrazing (in particular after the [Highland clearances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highland_Clearances) leaves most of the uplands as an ecological disaster area. What used to be rich and biodiverse rainforest is now barren peatland with here and there a plantation. Scotland is pretty, in particular the coast, but apart from a free corners (sheep-free Rùm is nice) it's very far from wild.

Answer (score 7):

I've spent some time in Southern Ukraine (Crimean Peninsula) and was impressed with the [Crimean Mountains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Mountains).  You can go for many km without seeing any people in the mountains there, though there is a large city in the center (Simferopol) of the peninsula and there are several large cities (Sevastopol, Yalta) on the coasts.

I was also impressed with [the Julian Alps in Slovenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Alps), which were very sparsely populated.

Answer (score 2):

The largest national park in Europe is Югыд ва or [Yugyd Va National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugyd_Va_National_Park).  It's 18,917 km² (near 10× the area of [Sarek National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarek_National_Park) or about twice the total area of the [Laponian Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laponian_area)), and part of the 32,800 km² [Virgin Komi Forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Komi_Forests).  The wilderness continues to the east of the protected area, but by then you'll have hiked into Siberia.  Only the Arctic [Nordaust-Svalbard Nature Reserve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordaust-Svalbard_Nature_Reserve) is a larger protected area (55,354 km²), but hiking there is not recommended due to the danger of polar bears.